# PHP Вывод рандомных чисел и сортировка

Tags: php, сортировка, случайные-числа

$m = 3; // Кол-во строк
 $n = 5; // Кол-во чисел в строке
Нужно сделать генерацию рандомных чисел и их сортировку

```
 $m = 3;$n = 5; 

for($r=0; $r<$m; $r++) {
    for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++) {
        $arr[$i] = rand(0,$n);
        asort($arr);
        foreach ($arr as $item) {
           print_r($item); 
        }
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: ваш код - _в студию!_

Comment: добавил код - можете посмотреть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы вставили вывод в цикл, в котором заполняете массив, поэтому выводите сначала одно число, потом два, потом три...

```
$m = 3;
$n = 5; 

for($r=0; $r<$m; $r++) {
    // делаем массив из n чисел 
    $arr = [];
    for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++) {
        $arr[] = rand(0,$n);
    }
    // сортируем массив и выводим 
    asort($arr);
    echo implode(' ',$arr); 
    echo "<br />\n";
}
```